# How to insert sections and hyperlinks in google maps infobox

Tags: google-maps, web

I need to insert a google map on my website, however I want to insert sections and hyperlinks to documents in the infobox, which i can't seem to do in google mymaps.

Using this website as reference: 
https://www.odense.dk/dagtilbud/dagplejen/dagpleje-syd?areaid=50&areaname=Syd

It has a map with a section. Within this there are markers. In the infobox of the markers there are hyperlinks to a document.

How and where do i get started with creating something similar?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Maps Platform's Maps JavaScript API](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to put a map in your website.

As for the infowindow in the marker, you can refer to the documentation [here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). This will help you put infowindows in *Maps JavaScript API*. There is a [sample code](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) that puts an html in your infowindow in the documentation. So to put a hyperlink in the info window you can use the **HTML a tag**.

e.g:

`<a href="https://www.yoursite.com/">yoursite.com</a>`

Then pass it as the content of the infowindow like this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<a href="https://www.yoursite.com/">yoursite.com</a>'
  });
```

If you want to open the link in a new tab use the **target="_blank"** in your a tag.

```
<a href="https://www.yoursite.com/" target="_blank">yoursite.com</a>
```

Here is a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/eqb4gthz/) that shows this.

Hope this helps!